# Confused about interaction terms in polynomial regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to code multivariate polynomial regression from scratch and I got confused about how interaction terms work. I saw that a polynomial regression with 2 inputs and with interaction terms should look like this: `ax^2 + bz^2 + cxz + dx + ez + f`, where `a,b,c,d,e,f` are the model's parameters and `x,z` are the inputs. But how would this equation look with 3 inputs? Would there be an interaction term with all three inputs `axyz` (`a` is a parameter)?

Comment: Do you just want squaring, or with the third term, so you also want terms raised to the third power? // You kind of get to pick what you want. If you just want to tack on a $+y$ term and can justify why, go for it.